# Android multiple instances of same activity

Tags: android, chat

Im developing a chat application.
I have faced a problem which im not sure how to solve. Im using FCM to send messages to each client. So I have a chat activity which contains all the messages from user x to user y.

When I receive a message from the FCM I have to check if:

1. Activity(user x) is not running -> start new chat with that user and pass message
2. Activity(user x) is in the background -> open chat and pass message
3. Activity(user x) is currently on the display -> pass message

Im not sure how to check if the chat activity with user x is not running, its in the background or its currently on the display.

I need a way of identifying instances of activitys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should do it different: Just update your model with the new message and let the UI (presenter) decide which chat should be shown based on the actions of the user (state). So basically notify your presenter that the data have changed and display the new data (messages) if they are relevant for the current conversation.

If the activity is not in the foreground you need to create a notification anyway so this should be no issue. The notification should tigger then that the right conversation should been displayed.

Comment: I agree. There should be no need to have an activity instance for each user. Just keep track of state and display the appropriate messages based on the state.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your use case/approach could benefit from using a [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute on your activity when declaring it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Add either a singleTop, or singleInstance option and use `onNewIntent()` to append new messages after the initial creation.